# Using Parsec with restrictions on parsed result

Tags: haskell, parsec, parse-error

I'm trying to come up with a clever way of parsing assembly code. For example, if the registers are numbered from 0 to 31, I want to accept `$31` but not `$32`.

I would like to do these while I parse the source code, because 1) I want to use the position information. 2) I like it simple.

My best idea is to use a special parser to indicate failure.

For example I could write

```
import Text.Parsec hiding (label)
import Text.Parsec.Token
import Text.Parsec.Language (emptyDef)
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec.Perm

data Register = Register Integer
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

register :: Parser Register
register = do char '$'
              n <- onlyWhen "Register number must be between 0 and 31" 
                            (\n -> n >= 0 && n <= 31) (decimal p)
              return $ Register n

onlyWhen :: String -> (a -> Bool) -> Parser a -> Parser a
onlyWhen mess pred pars 
  = do r <- pars
       if pred r then return r
                 else fail mess

p = makeTokenParser emptyDef
```

It works, but the error message contains traces of the parsing state, which is unfortunate.

What would be the best way to do it? Is there some additional library for doing this kind of things?

Comment: That error message seems decent—what would you like it to look like?

Comment: It would be better if the error message would be just my message, with error positon.

Comment: Should this sort of knowledge be part of the parser? It's not syntactical... I would be mightily confused if my compiler decided to spew a syntax error for an unbound variable or something

Comment: It's totally syntactical and should part of the parser.

Comment: Ah, you want to annotate the error with the error position? Some of the other parser combinator libraries besides Parsec do this---`uu-parsinglib` and `trifecta` off the top of my head---for all errors. Parsec takes slightly more effect: you can access the `SourcePos` of an error using `errorPos :: ParseError -> SourcePos`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to extract Error messages

```
getErrorMessage (ParseError p xs) = show p ++ concat $ map messageString xs
```